# svelte data from one component to other

Tags: svelte

please i have one question :
in Main.svelte components i have array footerItems :

```
<script>
 let footerItems = [
 {
 'left' : [
   {
     'id' : 'item #1',
     'value' : true 
   },
   {
     'id' : 'item#2',
     'value' : true 
   } 
 ],
 'right' : [
   {
     'id' : 'item#3',
     'value' : true
   }
 ]
 }
]
</script>
```

in components Data.svelte i have :

```
<script>
import Main from './components/Main.svelte';
export let footerItems;
let addData = {
    'id': 'map', 
    'value': false
};
    footerItems['left'].push(addData);
</script>
```

I need to add a new object to the footerItems ['left'] from the Data.svelte component.
can anyone advise me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Main.svelte and Data.svelte 'are connected' (Data 'sits' inside Main), you can simply pass in the array as a property with the bind: directive

###### [Main.svelte]

```html
<script>
  let footerItemsParent
</script>

<Data bind:footerItemsChild={footerItemsParent} />

<!-- or simply <Data bind:footerItems /> -->
<!-- if name of variable is the same in both parent and child component -->
```

###### [Data.svelte]

```html
<script>
  export let footerItemsChild;
</script>
```

With the bind: directive the variables are 'connected' and all modifications to the varible inside the component are changing the parent instance

If it's an array, it can be altered either by .push() **followed by an assignment** of the modified variable to itself **important** >> the assignment triggers the update where the variable is used

```js
array.left.push(addData)
array = array

//OR

array = [...array, addData]
```

Even if the assignment to itself looks a bit weird - when modifiying a nested field like in this case the .push syntax might be better to read, since first setting the subfield on a variable an then assigning the variable breaks the reactivity again

```js
let subArr = array[index].key
subArr = [...subArr, addData]    // not reactive

//OR

array[index].key.push(addData)
array = array                    // reactive


array[index].key = [...array[index].key, addData] // reactive, but harder to read
```

In case both Components have **no direct connection**, moving the footerItems to a **store** would be another solution.

###### [store.js]

```js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

export const footerItemsStore = writable(
 ...
 data
 ...
)
```

Inside the component the store can (after being imported) easily referenced by prefixing the store name with **$** ( = auto-subscription)

###### [Component.svelte]

```html
<script>
  import {footerItemsStore} from './store.js'

  $footerItemsStore = [...$footerItemsStore, newItem]
</script>
```

**NOTE** Neither the imported property from the parent component nor the store value can be directly modified on the top level of the script tag in the component => If the modification should happen with mounting the component, the functionality can happen in the [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) function

**Have a look at this** [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3d4583a2d1434e23a578abefac7c297d?version=3.44.0) with both the parent-child-component situation and the store alternative

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use writable / subscribe ..etc to manage your store. Also methods like push / splice can break reactivity (if you use)

In Main.svelte

```
export const footer =writable([
    {
        'left' : [
        {
        'id' : 'item #1',
        'value' : true 
        },
        {
        'id' : 'item#2',
        'value' : true 
        } 
        ],
        'right' : [
        {
        'id' : 'item#3',
        'value' : true
        }
        ]
        }
])
```

In Data.svelte

```
import {footer} from './store.js'

let leftSideArr
let addData = {
    'id': 'map', 
    'value': false
};

 
  footer.subscribe(val=>{
      leftSideArr=val[0].left
      leftSideArr=[...leftSideArr,addData]
  })
```